# unit test receiving binary response with $httpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a service that processes a binary response from a web API call:

```
$http.get('/endpoint', {
    params: urlparams,
    transformResponse: transform,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
```

Which I'm trying to test using $httpBackend:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/endpoint').respond(200, data);
```

But it doesn't work, because data is converted to JSON automatically and I couldn't find a way to specify the `responseType` in the `expectGET` call.

How can I make `expectGET` provide an binary response to the `$http.get` call? I've tried converting `data` to an `ArrayBuffer` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue and used:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/endpoint').respond(200, new Blob([data]));
```

I however had to update PhantomJs to 2.x from 1.x for this to work.